# random "connection aborted" error when calling query function of BigQuery python API

Tags: python, google-bigquery, chromebook

I have a "connection aborted" error when calling the query() function of the bigquery python API. I have a loop which calls one sql with API at a time. The weird thing is that the error happened randomly. If 10 queries are run, this time it may have 8 queries succeeded, 2 failed due to the "connection aborted" error. Next time, it may have 6 succeeded and 4 failed. I have run each sql individually through "bq query" command and BigQuery Console. The SQLs have no problem.

I run the program on Google Chromebook. Python version is 3.7.3 and the google-cloud-bigquery version is 2.31.0. The code snippet to call the API is as follows:

```
            client = bigquery.Client(project=cfg.project_id)
 
            job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_query_cache = False)
            if cfg.test_mode.lower() == "true":
                job_config.dry_run = True
                
            query_job = client.query(sql,
                job_config = job_config
            )
            query_job.result()  
            df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

The log of the error message is as follows:

```
2022-01-11 11:15:06,262.262 ERROR data_validator - run_a_testcase: Exception happens when processing query: DHCP#Null_relay_ip. Exception: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(functools.partial(<bound method JSONConnection.api_request of <google.cloud.bigquery._http.Connection object at 0x7d05e67bbba8>>, method='POST', path='/projects/ml-mps-app-ctp-anlys-d-ce71/jobs', data={'jobReference': {'jobId': '82e30ee3-380e-4481-98f4-67b473c623d0', 'projectId': 'ml-mps-app-ctp-anlys-d-ce71'}, 'configuration': {'query': {'useQueryCache': False, 'useLegacySql': False, 'query': "select count(*) from res_ctapprocessed_us_d.dhcpdemo where  last_activity BETWEEN cast('2021-10-12 16:00:00.000' as DATETIME) AND cast('2021-10-12 16:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)  and (relay_ip is null)"}, 'dryRun': True}}, timeout=None)), last exception: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')), 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1352, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 310, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1352, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 310, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 480, in api_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 338, in _make_request
    method, url, headers, data, target_object, timeout=timeout
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 376, in _do_request
    url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 486, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_validator.py", line 332, in run_a_testcase
    job_config = job_config
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3391, in query
    future = do_query()
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3368, in do_query
    query_job._begin(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py", line 1249, in _begin
    super(QueryJob, self)._begin(client=client, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 517, in _begin
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 782, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 291, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/home/s013949/py373/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 211, in retry_target
    last_exc,
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(functools.partial(<bound method JSONConnection.api_request of <google.cloud.bigquery._http.Connection object at 0x7d05e67bbba8>>, method='POST', path='/projects/ml-mps-app-ctp-anlys-d-ce71/jobs', data={'jobReference': {'jobId': '82e30ee3-380e-4481-98f4-67b473c623d0', 'projectId': 'ml-mps-app-ctp-anlys-d-ce71'}, 'configuration': {'query': {'useQueryCache': False, 'useLegacySql': False, 'query': "select count(*) from res_ctapprocessed_us_d.dhcpdemo where  last_activity BETWEEN cast('2021-10-12 16:00:00.000' as DATETIME) AND cast('2021-10-12 16:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)  and (relay_ip is null)"}, 'dryRun': True}}, timeout=None)), last exception: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Any comments are highly appreciated. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by changing the "mtu" setting of the network interface on Chromebook. The command is "sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1200". Thanks.